# Is there a way to combine 2 TEXT files based on a set of characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 2 text files that I need combined, the thing is, not all lines of the second file should be transferred over to the first file.

I have a small indicator code at the beginning of every line for

Heres a small example of both files:

```
000018ba5bb87cd78d  abcde
000018ba5bb87cd78d  34431
000018ba5bb87cd78d  lmoq1
000027e23c421aeec2  88888
000027e23c421aeec2  1qaz2
```

theres many more of these "indicators"

second file

```
000018ba5bb87cd78d  1st
000027e23c421aeec2  2nd
```

what im trying to output

```
000018ba5bb87cd78d  abcde 1st
000018ba5bb87cd78d  34431 1st
000018ba5bb87cd78d  lmoq1 1st
000027e23c421aeec2  88888 2nd
000027e23c421aeec2  1qaz2 2nd
```

I'm not quite sure if this is possible in notepad++ but i don't mind using any other kind of tool to help me achieve my goal

I've tried using regex but it doesn't quite get my anywhere at all
I've also tried looking up on here as well as on google but i'm not quite sure how to properly explain what i am looking to achieve without giving a example, which is quite hard thing to do on google

Comment: You might gave a chance to do that in Excel, using text-to-columns, vlookup and other functions and formulas. At the end, you should visually check the file anyway. Simply using regex is not going to work, what you need is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

I used excel as suggested by virolino, I had just pasted my txt in there and then on a second sheet I pasted the other txt, then on the first one in the third row I used the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

after that I just made it go across the entire column by double clicking the dot at the bottom right corner of A3 and then I just copied it out of there